How can I directly fetch feedback provided in the Chainlit UI to my app?
I'm currently developing an app using Chainlit and have enabled feedback options with the Literal API key. While I can view all threads, steps, and feedback on the Literal AI dashboard, I need to fetch the feedback comments directly from the UI to a chainlitapp.py file for additional purposes.
Are there any direct functions or methods within Chainlit that allow for fetching and storing these feedback comments locally? Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated.
I have created a custom data layer in Chainlit to handle feedback.
Here's the relevant part of my code:
class CustomDataLayer(cl_data.BaseDataLayer):

    async def upsert_feedback(self, feedback: cl_data.Feedback) -> str:
    
        return await super().upsert_feedback(feedback)

cl_data._data_layer = CustomDataLayer()

Within the upsert_feedback function, I can print the feedback provided, but I am unable to access this feedback object elsewhere in my chainlitapp.py file.
What I am expecting:
Guidance on how to access the feedback object outside the upsert_feedback function in my chainlitapp.py file.

Every time a user votes on a message, the upsert_feedback method is called. You could just store the feedback instance which is passed to the method in a database (e.g. redis or postgres) or in a file locally.
This medium article may help you: "Enable Human Feedback in Chainlit Without LITERAL API Key and Save Feedback")

Thank you, Lucas, for your response. I've read the article you provided and am using it to solve the problem below.
global run_id
run_id = None
class CustomDataLayer(cl_data.BaseDataLayer):
async def upsert_feedback(self, feedback: cl_data.Feedback) -> str:

    feedback_record = langsmith.client.create_feedback(
        run_id,
        score=feedback.value,
        comment=feedback.comment,
    )

To use run_id in upsert_feedback, I made it global as I can't pass it. Is there another method to get the latest feedback as a return object directly?

I'm also dealing with the issue to link the feedback directly to a message. I was using Langfuse instead of Langsmith for observation and could only access the id of the last trace (message sent & received). Therefore it works only if the user rates the latest message. If the user rates an older message it is linked to the latest trace (latest message).

oh! I see, Thank You for your response, Lucas.
